# Decimal point showing malformed number near '7.5' in Lua

Tags: lua, esp8266, nodemcu

I build the firmware at https://nodemcu-build.com/index.php, then downloaded and uploaded to ESP nodemcu-master-7-modules-2018-11-29-12-08-08-float.bin

Using ESPlorer for programming ESP8266.

a = 7.5

print(a)

This lua code shows error "malformed number near '7.5' "

I do not understand why?

older version nodemcu-master-9-modules-2018-07-08-13-12-54-float works fine

Comment: Just spoke with the developer at nodemcu-build about this, the error is fixed now. Go grab a fresh firmware!

Comment: Thanks, now it works :-)